# Magento 2 Enterprise : DB split in Percona

Tags: magento2, database, magento2-enterprise

We can use [DB split](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_slavedb.html) in Magento 2 Enterprise edition, but with Percona MySql 5.6 can we implement DB split?
Also do we have to add extra connection string in `app/env.php` or any module?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command below, it'll add automatically add the required config in your **env.php**, you can check the complete step-by-step to set up in Percona, MySQL or MariaDB **[here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_masterdb.html)**.

```
magento setup:db-schema:split-sales --host="localhost" --dbname="magento_sales" --username="magento_sales" --password="magento_sales"
```

Comment: Hi Rafael is it possible to Community Edition as Per Magento Dev doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html

it is possible with CE but this ( setup:db-schema:split-sales ) command is not available in CE